# Find minimum weighted set

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, np

I'm facing a deadend. Already searched trough stack forum, hope the question has not Already been asked..

I have a univers called U ( with Many elements). 
I have N sets containing several elements from U. We can find same element in different set.
Each set has a weight ( not related to the number of elements it contains).

I must find à algorithm that find the combinaison of sets, with a minimum weight, that contains at least all the elements from the univers.

I think its common issue ( Maybe a well known np complet problem)  but I can't tell myself that it's impossible. 
I'm looking for some ways to optimize but don't know where to begin with.

Any advices ?

Kind regards,

Yann

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Weighted set cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) problem.  It  is NP-Complete.

Comment: Thx, so I'm stuck =)

Comment: Sort of.  The greedy algorithm (choose  the set with the lowest cost per new covered element) often works well in practice, although it is only guaranteed to come within a factor of log(n) of the optimal solution.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I'll to understand this greedy algo =)